# Android Crash alert systems?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, crash-reports, hockeyapp

[Disclaimer: I looked around at the other stackexchange websites and couldn't find a perfect place to post this question, so i'll post it here. i'm happy to take it down and place it somewhere else if you know where this is supposed to be. please do not downvote because of that]

Currently we use a 3rd part tool (HockeyApp) for monitoring crash reports on an android app. They have an API that i can use to query for crash reports. I want to be able to have an automated crash report system where if certain conditions are met, i get an email (or maybe a phone call). For example, say i get 9001 crashes within an hour, i would like to receive an alert.

1. Is there a tool for doing this already? (crash monitoring for android, using hockeyapp is highly preferred)
2. I looked into rolling out my own Ruby on Rails app for doing this, using ActionMailer apis. has anyone had any experience with this and recommend it? Or what would be a better approach? (If i have to roll out my own tool, dev time is of the essence)
3. What kind of tools do your/other companies use for this kind of situation (crash alerting/pager duty)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can continue to use [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net) and set a [webhook](http://hockeyapp.net/blog/2013/08/06/hockeyapp-webhooks.html) when a new crash was created. This webhook can point to your own backend or to a service like [Zapier](https://zapier.com/help/pagerduty/), which can then trigger a PagerDuty, email or all kinds of notifications.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com/). They notify by email and send daily stats on email. For detailed stats you can visit your account. But this service is only for crashreporting.